# How to show loading image and disable button for 3 sec before start send post data from another page using ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to show loading image and disable button for 3 sec before start send post data from another page using ajax post ?

After press ok button i want to display loading image and disable

`<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="doajax_products_check()"/>`

for 3 sec and then start send requests to data.php

How can i do that ?

index.php

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" ENCTYPE = "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" style=" margin: 0px; " >
<input type="text" name="products_id" value="1294759">
<input type="text" name="products_color" value="red">
<input type="text" name="products_type" value="electronic">
<input type="button" value="Check" onclick="doajax_products_check()"/>
<p id="myplace_data"></p>
</form>

<script language="javascript">
function createAjax() {
    var request = false;
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    }
    catch (err2) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err3) {
            try {
                request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (err1) {
                    request = false;
            }
         }
    }
    return request;
}
</script>    
<script language="javascript">
function doajax_products_check(mydata) {
    var ajax1=createAjax(); 
    ajax1.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(ajax1.readyState==4 && ajax1.status==200){
            document.getElementById('myplace_data').innerHTML=ajax1.responseText;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    ajax1.open("POST","data.php",true);
    ajax1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    ajax1.send("products_color="+document.form1.products_color.value+"&products_type="+document.form1.products_type.value+"&products_id="+document.form1.products_id.value);
}
</script>
```

data.php

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['products_color']))
    {
        if ( $_POST['products_id'] != '' )
            { 
                if ( $_POST['products_type'] != '' )
                    {  
?>
<span class="taken_domain" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto; " >PRODUCTS DATA OK</span> 
<?PHP
         }
         else
         {
?>
<span class="taken_domain" style=" display: block; margin: 0 auto; " >NO PRODUCTS type</span> 
<?PHP
       }
    }
    else
    {
```

?>
   NO PRODUCTS ID
    
      }
    }
        else
            {
       ?>
       NO PRODUCTS COLOR
        
            }
        ?>

Comment: why are you trying ActiveX stuff first? that's old and super deprecated. `XMLHttpRequest` is the modern, standards-based replacement. you should use prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [settimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) function to delay the action.

```
function your_function() {
    // send requests to data.php
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
       setTimeout(your_function,3000); 
       // the function you called by setTimeout.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JQuery code:

```
function buttonClicked()
{
    $('#your_buttons_id').off('click'); // Disable button click
    $('#your_loader_element').show(); // Show loading element
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#your_loader_element').hide(); // Hide loading element
        $('#your_buttons_id').click(buttonClicked); // Enable button click
    }, 3000);
    doajax_products_check(your_data); // Call to ajax
}

$(function(){
    $('#your_buttons_id').click(buttonClicked); // Enable button click on page load
});
```

Comment: WHERE code for dispaly loading and disable button for 3 sec?

Comment: @papmooo Please see I have added comments and code for 'loading'.

Answer (score 0):

try to use blockui http://malsup.com/jquery/block/
Block ui gives you the same effect and also is extendable to many views